# htaccess template rewrite with full url in path

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I go about setting up a htaccess template rewrite where the url rewrite path contains a url?

Something like:

```
https://mysite.test/results/http://mycrawled.site/page/
```

I have seen this behavior on hubspots website grader.

This is my current redirect rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^results/(.*)$ /tpl/results.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

With the current rule any double slashes in the url query parameter are converted to single slashes

Such as: From `http://mycrawled.site` to `http:/mycrawled.site`.

How do I go about correcting this rewrite so the url parameter is not modified?

**Update**

So after some testing, I have found the cause of the problem. There is a remove trailing slash rule which is stripping the second slash from the url

```
# Remove Trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [r=301,l]
```

How can I work around this conflict?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Encode the value and pass it to URL. by doing this you don't need to be worry about the value and slashes. at the end decode the value and you will have the exact result

```
$fullURL = 'http://your-website.com/results.php?url=' + urlencode('http://example.com');
```

and then decode it later

```
$result = urldecode($_GET['url']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility could be to validate the http: (or https: ) part as match, after that one for the domain and finally for the remote path. After that just concatenate again.

Advantage: you can explicitly check the domainname for use of https, and you can use the domainname separately as well. In the example below (untested!) you could move the colon into the first match. In that case you could use the rule for non-urls as well (though I would advice not to).

```
RewriteRule ^results/(https?)://(.*?)/(.*)$ /tpl/results.php?url=$1://$2/$3 [L,QSA]
```

So, when using your example `http://mycrawled.site/page`:

- $1 = http or https (here: http)
- $2 = domainname (here: mycrawled.site)
- $3 = path (here: page)